# Unable to assign certificate using Cert-Manager and NGINX ingress controller in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I am using Nginx Ingress controller(Internal Ingress) and Cert-manger 0.15.1 helm charts. Kubernetes version: 1.14.x

My certificate status is not coming to to True. I have tried using both types of challengers DNS01 and HTTP01. Its the same.
Error:

```
Attaching screen shots[![Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate][1]][1]
```

cluster-issuer.yaml

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
 name: letsencrypt-staging
 namespace: cert-manager
spec:
 acme:
   # The ACME server URL
   server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
   # Email address used for ACME registration
   email: <email>
   # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
   privateKeySecretRef:
     name: letsencrypt-staging
   # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
   solvers:
   - http01:
       ingress:
         class:  nginx
```

Ingress.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-devtools-ilb-https
  namespace: <>
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - domain.con
      secretName: create-new-secret
  rules:
    - host: domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-service
              servicePort: hello-port
          - path: "/kube"
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-kubernetes
              servicePort: 80
```

kubectl describe certificate create-new-secret

```
Name:         create-new-secret
Namespace:    
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2020-07-19T13:30:01Z
  Generation:          1
  Owner References:
    API Version:           extensions/v1beta1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  <ingress-name>
    UID:                   f0b74bb6-c903-11ea-9960-4201ac100008
  Resource Version:        521536
  Self Link:               /apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2/namespaces/<namesapce>/certificates/create-new-secret
  UID:                     f2b63e87-c9c3-11ea-bb3e-4201ac100004
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    domain.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       Issuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-staging
  Secret Name:  create-new-secret
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2020-07-19T13:30:02Z
    Message:               Waiting for CertificateRequest "create-new-secret-2447513806" to complete
    Reason:                InProgress
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age   From          Message
  ----    ------        ----  ----          -------
  Normal  GeneratedKey  3m8s  cert-manager  Generated a new private key
  Normal  Requested     3m8s  cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "create-new-secret-2447513806"
```

Please help me in resolving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this with the help of DNS01

## Letsencrypt-prod certificate issuer ILB

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: cert-issuer
  namespace: <>
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: 
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: dns-prod-issuer
    solvers:
      - selector: {}
        dns01:
          clouddns:
            project: GCP_project_ID
            serviceAccountSecretRef:
              name: clouddns-dns01-solver-svc-acct
              key: key.json
```

## Letsencrypt-prod certificate

```
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: cert
  namespace: <>
spec:
  secretName: cert-secret
  issuerRef:
    name: cert-issuer
    kind: Issuer
  dnsNames:
    - host.domain.com
    - www.host.domain.com
```

## Ingress

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-https
  namespace: <>
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "'"
            backend:
              serviceName: 
              servicePort: 
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - host.domain.com
      secretName: cert-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are using `staging` server from Let's Encrypt.
The `staging` server is used only for tests, and after you consider it's ok you can move to `production` servers.

You need to create a new issuer using [this](https://github.com/JessicaGreben/example-nodejs/blob/master/deploy/cert-manager-setup/letsencrypt-clusterissuer-prod.yaml) examples

After change your ingress annotation to :

```
cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-production"
```

**References:**

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/